# Upgrading WP Version + Keeping Customized Core Code?

Tags: upgrade

I'm a WP noob, so please bear with me.

I'm working on my first WP project, and my task is to extract all the customized core WP code and put them into other files so that in the future when we upgrade the WP version, it'll be more maintainable and our customized core code won't be deleted.

1.

I noticed that there are a few PHP embedded HTML pages such as `/wordpress-3.2.1/wp-includes/admin-bar.php` where the difference is that

this

```
    function _admin_bar_bump_cb() { ?>
    <style type="text/css" media="screen">
        html { margin-top: 28px !important; }
        * html body { margin-top: 28px !important; }
    </style>
    <?php
    }
```

becomes this:

```
    function _admin_bar_bump_cb() { ?>
    <!-- <style type="text/css" media="screen">
        html { margin-top: 28px !important; }
        * html body { margin-top: 28px !important; }
    </style> -->
    <?php
```

I also have a page where I add customized javascript `<script>...</script>` in my `wordpress-3.0.5/wp-admin/admin-header.php` file. Where would I place it to make sure it's loaded when I upgrade the WP version?

2.

And how about customized functions? Here's an example of one of the methods in `wp-admin/includes/template.php` :

Original code:

```
    function meta_form() {
        global $wpdb;
        $limit = (int) apply_filters( 'postmeta_form_limit', 30 );
        $keys = $wpdb->get_col( "
            SELECT meta_key
            FROM $wpdb->postmeta
            GROUP BY meta_key
            HAVING meta_key NOT LIKE '\_%'
            ORDER BY meta_key
            LIMIT $limit" );
        if ( $keys )
            natcasesort($keys);
    ?>
```

Customized version:

```
function meta_form() {
    global $wpdb;

  if ( isset($_GET['post']) )
    $post_id = (int) $_GET['post'];
  elseif ( isset($_POST['post_ID']) )
    $post_id = (int) $_POST['post_ID'];
  else
    $post_id = 0;

  if ( $post_id ) {
    $post_ = get_post($post_id);

  }

  if ($post_->post_type == 'video_photo' ){
    $limit = (int) apply_filters( 'postmeta_form_limit', 30 );
    $keys = $wpdb->get_col( "
        SELECT meta_key
        FROM $wpdb->postmeta
    where meta_key like 'tqmcf_%'
        GROUP BY meta_key
        HAVING meta_key NOT LIKE '\_%'
        ORDER BY meta_key
        LIMIT $limit" );
  }else{
    $limit = (int) apply_filters( 'postmeta_form_limit', 30 );
    $keys = $wpdb->get_col( "
        SELECT meta_key
        FROM $wpdb->postmeta

        GROUP BY meta_key
        HAVING meta_key NOT LIKE '\_%'
        ORDER BY meta_key
        LIMIT $limit" );
  }

    if ( $keys )
        natcasesort($keys);
?>
```

Where exactly would I define my `meta_form()` function to make sure it overwrites the core method? I read stuff on add_filter and add_action, but I have no clue how to implement them or how they actually work.

Comment: Somebody has to say it: don't change core files! Create theme files and plugins to modify or override core functionality. That way you are more future proof. Sorry you're in that boat.

Comment: I didn't write it! How would I fix it

Comment: you've got a few unrelated questions here that may be best as individual questions. you can probably find answers to the fist two by searching this site, for example- remove admin bar css, how to add javascript to admin pages.

Comment: Dunno man. If you're able to compare two files and learn what has been changed, you are going to be better off trying to move those custom functions to the themes `functions.php` file or writing one or more plugins to handle the changes. Honestly, for a beginner I think theme development is a little easier. But it ties all those changes to your theme. Read here for a start: http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development

Comment: The answer to this is really the same as I gave for your other, very similar, question: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/103664/21376 This is a hard road. Maybe we can tackle this hack by hack but I doubt there is a generic answer to undoing the core modifications especially since 3.0.5 is a long way from 3.5.1

Comment: I concur that this would make more sense as individual questions rather than one with multiple unrelated points in code.

Comment: You're in a very, very bad situation. One thing that might come to **help** is `git` - no joke. Git has a pretty awesome diff tool, that [an diff whole directories](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2746292/376483). This should bring you a big step towards finding those hacks.